# Por que no puedo conectarme a SQL Server?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2

Intento conectarme a una base de datos local con la cadena de conexión que ofrece `Visual Studio` en el explorador de objetos `SQL`.

El código es el siguiente:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=GS1512;Initial Catalog=sxUnimageDev;Integrated Security=True;User ID=sa;Password=********;Connect Timeout=30;Encrypt=False;TrustServerCertificate=False;ApplicationIntent=ReadWrite;MultiSubnetFailover=False");
    myCon.Open();

    MessageBox.Show("Conectado");
}
```

Al ejecutar la aplicación se queda tratando de conectar, no muestra mensajes de error.

Finalmente carga el formulario pero el mensaje "Conectado" no lo ejecuta.

Gracias si me pueden ayudar.

Comment: Dos cosas, primero verifique que el servicio `MSSQL` este corriendo y luego, vea si tiene algún error en la cadena de conexión, aquí estan todos los métodos de conexión permitidos con SQL Server: https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/

Comment: posiblemente la cadena de conexion este mal,verifica que la cadena de conexion tenga accesos a la bd usando el explorador de servidores

Comment: Además de las sugerencias que ya te han hecho, la cadena de conexión tiene un error en Integrated Security = True, si vas a utilizar usuario y password este valor debería estar en "False".

Comment: Intenta primero con la siguiente cadena y si deseas después le adicionas los otros parámetros:  "Data Source=GS1512;Initial Catalog=sxUnimageDev;Integrated Security=False;User ID=sa;Password=********; "

Comment: Gracias. Fueron muy utiles tus sugerencias.

Answer (score 0):

Te sugiero dos cosas:

1. que no metas la cadena de conexión en duro en tu código, ya que luego, si necesitas cambiarla por lo que sea, tendrás que volver a compilar tu código. Es más efectivo que uses el fichero de configuración web.config o app.config, y accedas a los valores en tu código usando la clase System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.
2. que metas todo en un bloque try/catch, pongas un punto de interupción en myCon.Open(); y ejecutes el depurador. Después el flujo debería saltar dentro del bloque catch, donde podrás ver más detalles del error. De hecho, lo más correcto es que usaras un logger para arrojar todos los errores a un fichero y poder analizarlo cuando lo necesites. Te recomiendo NLog o Serilog.

Quedaría algo similar a esto:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        SqlConnection myCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["miConexion"]);
        myCon.Open();

        MessageBox.Show("Conectado");
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _mylogger.Error("Oops!!! Algo fue mal: ", ex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Gracias. Fueron muy utiles tus sugerencias.

Comment: Me alegro que te resultara útil. Podrías marcarla entonces como respuesta correcta?